# Setting up a pay as you go phone for a friend, it asked for an email, and i entered mine. Now they have access to my emails. How do I take it off?

Tags: gmail, google-account, email

Setting up a pay as you go phone for a friend, it asked for an email, and i entered mine.  Now my friend has access to my emails.  Why did they need this? and How do I take it off?

Comment: You should have had your friend enter their Gmail account, have them setup a new account if they don't have one, or just skip that portion. Logging out or changing your Google password could be more dangerous, without removing the account from the device properly could kick in Factory Reset Protection. Work with your friend and deleted the account from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke access to your account on your Gmail settings page
Please take a look on this answer
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6264236?hl=en

Comment: Or simply remove the account from the phone Menu > Account > Google

Comment: On the problem it looks like it is not your phone, so you dont have access to it.. @esQmo_

Answer (score 0):

Open settings>accounts>Google>open menu (three dots on the top right)>remove account.

Some phones will not let you remove the first account, in that case you can

1.factory reset the phone (settings>backup and rest>factory data reset) have in mind that this will delete all saved data on the phone.

2. Or root your phone and remove account manually.

When setting up the phone there should have been an option to skip, instead of adding Google account.
The point of adding your Google account would be to have everything backed up and sync all data between all devices.